# Why lift 3 round trips are doing 2 kinds of HTTP request

Tags: lift

I am using lift 3 round trip and I am trying to understand what happens behind the scene.

Why are there 2 kinds of request :

- GET on comet_request
- POST on ajax_request

Answer (score 3):

Lift's uses HTTP Long Polling for asynchronous responses to the browser.  I won't go into great detail on why the Lift developers have chosen Long Polling over other implementations, like Web Sockets, but there are well thought out reasons and if you're interested just do a quick search through the Lift mailing list where it's been discussed many times.

The gist of how it works is that the browser makes a request to the server, and the server holds the request open until there is information to send.  When information becomes available, it gets pushed down the pipe, the browser processes it, and the browser initiates a new long poll request.  Lift uses the servlet container's asynchronous support to hold the connection open with very little resource consumption, and because Javascript is asynchronous by nature, waiting on new information is not resource intensive for the browser either.  Since there is a limit on the number of requests a browser can make to the same domain at once, Lift only opens one of these long poll connections at a time and multiplexes responses from what could be many different "responders" through it.

Initially Lift's asynchronous support was added so that data generated by server side events could be pushed to the client as they occurred.  With the growth in popularity of client side frameworks, the ability to push asynchronous data initiated by client events became useful, hence the addition of round trips.  The idea is that the client makes a request to the server, and rather than respond immediately, the server does some stuff in another thread then sends a response (potentially much) later.  To users of the client side API, this is modeled as a promise, but behind the scenes what happens is that Lift receives the request and responds immediately (remember, we can't have too many requests open to the same domain) but will stream the actual data that satisfies the promise through the long polling connection when it becomes available.

So, that's what you're seeing.  Your initial request is the ajax POST, which triggers the beginning of a round trip.  If you were to look at the data returned by that request, you'd see that it's not the data that satisfies the promise.  The actual response data is delivered via Lift's long polling mechanism, and that is what you see with the GET request.